# Perl To Parse Whitespace Separated Columns

Tags: perl, parsing, whitespace

I have a large text file which has three columns present, each column separated by four spaces.  I need a perl script to read this text file and output columns #1, and #2 to a new text file with each of these columns wrapped in quotation marks and separated commas in the output file.

The text file with the four columns has data which looks like this:

```
    9a2ba3c0580b5f3799ad9d6f487b2d3    /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7_name_PC/images/filename.jpg    HOST
```

What I would like the output to look like is

```
"9a2ba3c0580b5f3799ad9d6f487b2d38","/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7_name_PC/images/filename.jpg"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy as a one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'print join ",", map qq("$_"), @F[0, 1]'
```

- `-l` handles newlines in `print`
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the `@F` array
- `@F[0, 1]` is an array slice, it extracts the first two elements of the `@F` array
- `map` wraps each element in double quotes
- `join` inserts the comma in between

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  Here is the output that I get:
String found where operator expected at parse4.pl line 2, near "lane 'print join ",", map qq("$_"), @F[0, 1]'"
        (Do you need to predeclare lane?)
syntax error at parse4.pl line 2, near "lane 'print join ",", map qq("$_"), @F[0, 1]'"
Execution of parse4.pl aborted due to compilation errors.  I am using Perl v5.18.2.

Comment: @QuePID: Run the whole line in a shell with the file name appended. It's not a script, it's a one-liner.

Comment: Works great as a one-liner, how could I convert to script?

Comment: @QuePID: Change the shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/perl -lan`, put `print join ',', map qq("$_"), @F[0, 1]` on the second line.

Comment: What if I want to use a fixed filename and have output piped to a new file?  As it works if I run the script and pass it the filename to parse, and manually pipe to new file.

Answer (score 0):

Below code for your reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $defaultFileName=defined $ARGV[0]?$ARGV[0]:"filename.txt";
die "Could not find file: $defaultFileName" unless(-f $defaultFileName);
open my $fh, '<',"textFileName.log";
foreach my $line(<$fh>) {
    my @tmpData=split(/\s+/, $line);
    printf "\"%s\",\"%s\"\\n\n",$tmpData[1],$tmpData[2];
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: 1) You should check the success of `open` instead of checking for file existence with `-f`: `open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;` Right now you have a race condition. 2) You can use `split(' ', $line)` to ignore leading whitespace. 3) Perl has string interpolation, so unless you need to do special formatting, `print`/`say` is generally preferable to `printf`. In this case, I would go a step further and use `map` + `join`, e.g. `my @fields = split(' ', $line); say( join(',', map qq{"$_"}, @fields) );` or something like that. 4) Always `use strict;` and `use warnings 'all';`

Answer (score -1):

This can also be done with `awk`

```
>>cat test
9a2ba3c0580b5f3799ad9d6f487b2d3    /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7_name_PC/images/filename.jpg    HOST
9a2ba3c0580b5f3799ad9d6f487b2d3    /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7_name_PC/images/filename.jpg    HOST
9a2ba3c0580b5f3799ad9d6f487b2d3    /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7_name_PC/images/filename.jpg    HOST
9a2ba3c0580b5f3799ad9d6f487b2d3    /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7_name_PC/images/filename.jpg    HOST
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>awk '{FS="    "}{print "\""$1"\",""\""$2"\",""\""$3"\"" }' test
"9a2ba3c0580b5f3799ad9d6f487b2d3","/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7_name_PC/images/filename.jpg","HOST"
"9a2ba3c0580b5f3799ad9d6f487b2d3","/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7_name_PC/images/filename.jpg","HOST"
"9a2ba3c0580b5f3799ad9d6f487b2d3","/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7_name_PC/images/filename.jpg","HOST"
"9a2ba3c0580b5f3799ad9d6f487b2d3","/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7_name_PC/images/filename.jpg","HOST"

>>awk '{FS="    "}{print "\""$1"\",""\""$2"\",""\""$3"\"" }' test > output.txt
```

then `output.txt` will have a desired output.

Comment: It can also be done with Ruby, Python, Java, C++, and C, among others, but that's not what the question asked about.